# Text box resize issue: difference between BIDS and browser rendering

Tags: text, reporting-services

When designing and previewing a report in BIDS everything looks fine, but once rendered in a web browser the text boxes resize. I've tried a few things to stop this including using rectangles as place holders. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Here are some screenshots. First design view:

[image: Design view]

Render view:

[image: Render view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, SSRS is not a very good tool for precise rendering. I've had the issue describe in various forms before, and can only offer a few options:

1. **Don't care.** Design your report in a way that it doesn't matter how it's *exactly* rendered.
2. **Focus on one renderer.** Don't optimize for both the BIDS Preview *and* the HTML rendering, but only on the final one (probably HTML). Note that with HTML you do have to deal with cross-browswer issues.
3. **Use tables for layout.** I know, this is [frowned upon in CSS land](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html), and I personally don't like it either. But a matrix may be your best bet at approaching pixel-perfectness, and from your screenshot it even looks like you have tabular data so it's even possible to rationalize the choice.
4. **Choose another renderer**. Deliver your report in Excel instead of HTML. With Excel it should be easier to get to a nicely layouted table.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I expected similar answers tbh. Problem is the data I deal with is live production which rules out excel and the layout I use is quite important, unfortunately a tablix was rejected earlier in a meeting. Predominantly the layout issues are overlooked but from a professional point of view in the large company I work for it are defiantly something I should be seen to be addressing.

This was a pilot report, I think I'll go for a different layout for the future.

Thanks.